# Eclipse project explorer retains focus when opening a file

Tags: eclipse

Opening a file in Eclipse's Project Explorer with a double click opens the file in the built-in editor but does not transfer the focus to the file for immediate editing. Instead the focus remains in the Project Explorer and a further click in the editor window or tab is required before editing or moving around the document. I guess this is by design but I am hoping there is an option or workaround of some kind. Thanks.

Using Eclipse 3.7.2 with C++ development tools installed on Ubuntu 12-04

Comment: Workaround: Press `F12` to set the focus on the editor.